# Why is $ f:x \mapsto bx $homomorphic?

Tags: group-homomorphism, rational-functions

More specifically, if I'm looking at a map: $f : (\mathbb{Q}, +)  \to (\mathbb{Q}, +)$, and $f$ maps $x$ to $bx$, where $b$ is some rational number, why would this be homomorphic?

Here's what I've tried:
$$f(pq) = bpq$$
but 
$$f(p) \cdot f(q) = ap \cdot cq $$
(I guess $ac$ can equal to $b$ but how do I know for sure?)

$$f(p+q) = b(p+q)$$
$$f(p) + f(q) = ap + cq$$
How do I prove that $a=c=b$?

Comment: Why did you introduce $a$ and $c$? You *have* the definition of $f(p)$, and it's $f(p) = bx$.

Comment: but even if f(p) = bp and f(q) = bq, then the product would be b^2pq

Answer (score 1):

Note that the groups are written with addition. Therefore to get a homomorphism it has to be $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.
Then $f(x+y)=b(x+y)=bx+by=f(x)+f(y)$.